# How can there be an "else" in python without an "if"

Tags: python, syntax

The following python code prints "no" as it should

```
for _ in range(10):
    a = 5+i
    if a > 50:
       print ("yes")
print("no")
```

But so does the following

```
for _ in range(10):
    a = 5+i
    if a > 50:
       print ("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I've never seen an else without an if in other languages, yet here the else seems to line up with the for. How is this possible? Shouldn't Python regard the second version as a syntax error?

I entered something like the second version by accident in a larger script and the script seemed to work. I didn't understand why.

Comment: Did you try looking up the syntax for Python's for-loop? It explains that in detail. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: Python allows for/else loops but in my experience aren't used very often. In other words, you are confused because you are associating the else with an if but it is associated with the for loop.